# Enqueue callback not called

Tags: android, mysql, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 and recognized that sometimes the callback for Call.enqueue is not called.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(usuarioService.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(usuarioService.g)).build();
usuarioService service = retrofit.create(usuarioService.class);
Call<String> user = service.verificarUsuario(login.getText().toString(), senha.getText().toString());
user.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
        String resultado = response.body();

        if (resultado.equals("false")) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Senha ou usuário não existente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            if (resultado.equals("true")) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ACESSO PERMITIDO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuDrawer.class);
                intent.putExtra("chave1", login.getText().toString());

                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

Suddenly that problem start to happen, does anybody knows how to fix it? These issue do not happen until some moments ago, I do not know what happened.

These happened just when i'm using mobile data, but when i'm used WIFI these never happened yet.

Answer (score 2):

You have empty onFailure implementation so callback may be called but nothing happens. Try to log some information in onFailure method.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
   Log.w("MyTag", "requestFailed", t); 
}
```

And you'll see if request failed and why.

Comment: But its not entering on that part of code `user.enqueue(new Callback<String>()`.

Comment: Oh! Why I leave it blank? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed my IP and fixed. I don't know why. But works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to look for is as [Josef Adamcik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135837/josef-adamcik) said in `onFailiure`.

The second thing that you might want to check calling the api directly, like in `onCreate` or `onViewCreated`.

When I called the api inside another function, i did not get both the callbacks, both success and failure, because it was **under a try catch block** and *inside the catch block there was nothing, no logs* or you are searching for the wrong tag in logcat. So try removing try catch if your code is surrounded by it or **put Log.e inside the catch block** and try again. Some errors like  @FormUrlEncoded not present can hit the catch block and if you don't have a Log.e inside the catch block, you will never know why your api is not getting called.